# Disable Drop on root node in SmartGWT

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I am using the following example of SmartGWT :

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#tree_interaction_drag_nodes

And i want to disable dropping of any node on the root node. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I never did it but I will try with `setCanAcceptDrop(false)`, for example:

```
TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode();
    rootNode.setCanAcceptDrop(false);
    rootNode.setID("0");
    rootNode.setAttribute("Name","ROOT");       
    rootNode.setIcon("16/root.png");
    tree.setRoot(rootNode);
```

Comment: I suppose the SmartGWT takes the whole tree as root node in the example given..i just want to disable drop of nodes on **bin3** folder and allow dropping on blue green and yellow parts.

Comment: Do you mean that when you get your bin3 node and setCanAcceptDrop to false it doesn't work? (Can you show piece of code)

Comment: The code is same as the code in example. I tried it as follows :    
    `TreeNode rootNode = new PartsTreeNode("Root",
                    new PartsTreeNode("Bin 3",
                            new PartsTreeNode("Blue Part",   "piece_blue.png"),
                            new PartsTreeNode("Green Part", "piece_green.png"),
                            new PartsTreeNode("Yellow Part", "piece_yellow.png")
                    )
            );`    
 But its not working. The problem is it doesn't get added to any of the leaves too. And also the node that is dragged disappears after it is dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Use "setCanAcceptDroppedRecords(false)" command.